Как в Jaspersoft iReport Designer сделать макет для вывода xls c несколькими вкладками?
Как в Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.6.0 создть макет так, чтобы на выходе получить отчет в формате Excel (xls) c несколькими вкладками?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! вряд ли вас интересует буквальный ответ на ваш вопрос. переформулируйте, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) так, чтобы на него можно было дать полноценный ответ

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
